# Saving dropbox file in path

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This gives me...

```
NSString *filename2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/newFile.json"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename2]];

[self.restClient loadFile:filename2 intoPath:getImagePath];


NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];  

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];
```

...this error:

File loaded into path: (null)

...but why?? this code was under view did load. the file is in dropbox, so what is the problem

Comment: Try logging getImagePath. What does is print?

Comment: /Users/alex/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/6C460043-6D30-4C6A-ACAB-72F869C97B17/Documents/newFile.json,  so the file is existent. May be it is not replaced

Comment: Are you executing the application into a sandbox? Did you check the values of documentsDirectory, getImagePath and fileContent variables with NSLog() function?

Comment: Did you authorize Dropbox and log in?

Comment: yes to all, may be it is because since a file with that name already exists, it is not replacing it

Comment: In this way I deleted the previous file: NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:getImagePath error:NULL];...but no way...so it must be a dropbox error

Comment: Try debugging it. Put a breakpoint on the loadFile: line and then go through it step by step. Or search your project (cmd-shift-F) for "File loaded into path" and see if you find any explanation there. (The Dropbox SDK is open-source isn't it?)

Comment: yes,  Dropbox SDK is open-source